# conversion from 'bool' to non-scalar type 'ManetAddress' requested

Tags: c++

I have this error "conversion from 'bool' to non-scalar type 'ManetAddress' requested" I only know it has something to do with the .H file but i do not know what is the error. ANybody mind helping? thanks a lot.

```
Class file:    

bool ManetRoutingBase::omnet_exist_rte(struct in_addr dst)
{
    //ManetAddress add = omnet_exist_rte(dst.s_addr);
    ManetAddress add = omnet_exist_rte(dst);
    if (add.isUnspecified()) return false;
    else if (add.getIPv4() == IPv4Address::ALLONES_ADDRESS) return false;
    else return true;
}


RoutingBase.H file

    virtual ManetAddress omnet_exist_rte(ManetAddress dst);     //FIXME revise return values


    virtual bool omnet_exist_rte (in_addr dst);   //FIXME remove it, use the another version
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in this statement:

```
ManetAddress add = omnet_exist_rte(dst);
```

Here you call the function recursively and assign the boolean result to something else.

---

You have two overloads of the function `omnet_exist_rte`. The compiler knows which one to call by looking at the argument you use. If you use `struct in_addr` it will call the function that takes an `struct in_addr` argument (and which returns `bool`).

To call the function which return a `ManetAddress`, you have to call it with an *argument* of type `ManetAddress`.

As you have now, since you use the same argument type, it will call the same function recursively (over and over again, leading to a stack overflow). However, since you try to assign the `bool` return value to a `ManetAddress` the compiler gives an error (since `ManetAddress` and `bool` are not compatible).

What you must do is create a variable of type `ManetAddress`, and use that variable to call the function:

```
ManetAddress new_dst;
// TODO: Convert from `struct in_addr` to `ManetAddress`...

ManetAddress add = omnet_exist_rte(new_dst);
```